# Chronicle-Map: ClassNotFoundException with Gradle & AspectJ

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj, chronicle, chronicle-map

I've encountered the following exception in an application that is being built with Gradle and uses AspectJ.
The app works fine when started from within Eclipse but fails to start once built with Gradle:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.openhft.chronicle.hash.VanillaGlobalMutableState$$Native
at net.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel.createClass(ValueModel.java:313) ~[chronicle-values-1.0.3-alpha.jar!/:na]
at net.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel.createNativeClass(ValueModel.java:286) ~[chronicle-values-1.0.3-alpha.jar!/:na]
at net.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel.nativeClass(ValueModel.java:268) ~[chronicle-values-1.0.3-alpha.jar!/:na]
at net.openhft.chronicle.values.Values.nativeClassFor(Values.java:51) ~[chronicle-values-1.0.3-alpha.jar!/:na]
at net.openhft.chronicle.values.Values.newNativeReference(Values.java:38) ~[chronicle-values-1.0.3-alpha.jar!/:na]
at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.VanillaChronicleHash.createGlobalMutableState(VanillaChronicleHash.java:324) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.VanillaChronicleHash.initOwnTransients(VanillaChronicleHash.java:373) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.VanillaChronicleHash.initTransients(VanillaChronicleHash.java:369) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.initTransients(VanillaChronicleMap.java:146) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.<init>(VanillaChronicleMap.java:102) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.newMap(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1703) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.lambda$createWithFile$93(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1449) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder$$Lambda$7/78866071.fileIOAction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.lambda$fileLockedIO$92(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:182) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder$$Lambda$8/862681096.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.fileLockedIO(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:179) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createWithFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1447) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1400) ~[chronicle-map-3.5.0-rc.jar!/:3.5.0-rc]
```

In my build.gradle I have:

```
    compile "net.openhft:chronicle-map:3.5.0-rc"
```

I've also tried this with earlier versions, without success.

One thing I have noticed when starting from Eclipse is that this new warning shows up when Chronicle is fist accessed:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor  'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.annotations.ServiceProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.annotations.DocumentationProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
```

but I am not sure if that is related.
Am I missing some other dependency?

Edit: I should also mentioned that I use Spring and that my Chronicle map is instantiated as part of a Spring bean.

Edit 2: Debug logging didn't yield anything useful. I'll try to downgrade to an older version of chronicle map next.

Edit 3: It works when building with

```
compile "net.openhft:chronicle-map:2.4.12"
```

Edit 4: Same error with new 3.6.0-rc

Edit 5: I have

```
compile files(org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getToolsJar())
```

in my build.gradle in order to add the tools.jar (Gradle doesn't have provide afaik). It is also part of the resulting (fat) jar file that I start.

Comment: I've seen similar issue, when `net.openhft:compiler:2.2.2` dependency is used, no issue with `net.openhft:compiler:2.2.1`. I don't know the reason for this issue, but I suspect it could be related to OSGi and class loading. Also if you try to start with `-ea` (assertions enabled), Slf4j configured to max verbosity level, and paste additional outputs, it would be helpful.

Comment: `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug`

Comment: About edit 3: no surprise, because Chronicle Map 2.x doesn't use dynamic class loading.

Comment: Is there  any downside to using 2.x? Still seems to be maintained? I noticed though that my (simple) tests for it are not working anymore. Is there any API change (except for ChronicleMapBuilder) which are not obvious?

Comment: About the issue: better to continue here: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values/issues/5 and delete this question (because it doesn't fit SO format). About the last question: if Chronicle Map 2.x is OK for you it is OK, beware there are many limitations in 2.x that are absent in 3.x. Also more features.

Comment: See https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#difference-between-chronicle-map-2-and-3

Comment: please check Chronicle Map version 3.6.0-rc, it is aimed to resolved this issue.

Comment: Please ensure that you have tools.jar in the classpath

Comment: Adent, I cannot investigate this issue without additional help from you, for example minimum reproducible example, because the current info is not sufficient.

Comment: BTW note that on Stackoverflow it's better to answer in comments than by question edits, because 1) it looks more like conversation, future readers shouldn't jump and understand which edit follows which comment; 2) people are not notified about question edits, but they are notified about the comments where they are mentioned.

Comment: Ok @leventov. I have created an example which you can find here: https://github.com/geld0r/ChronicleMapExample Note that this is probably not a minimal build configuration (yet). Let me know when you need additional information.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will investigate this

Comment: It works for me both from Intellij and command line, via `gradle bootRun`, on both WIndows and Linux.

Comment: Interesting. For me it also works with 'gradle bootRun'. If I start the resulting jar with 'java -jar' though it fails. Can you try that, too?

Comment: @leventov can you check that, too? I don't know what could cause this difference...

Comment: I believe I know the reason for the problem and I'm in the process of fixing it

Comment: Awesome! Let me know once you have a solution. I am happy to try that out.

Comment: Try `3.7.0-rc`, should fix the issue now.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it. Application now starts and also seems to work (from first glance) but I receive following warnings repeatedly on startup: `/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/VanillaGlobalMutableState.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'net.openhft.chronicle.values.Group': class file for net.openhft.chronicle.values.Group not found`. Same for methods "min()" and "max()". Can that be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chronicle Map version `3.7.0-rc` doesn't have this issue. It emits some no-harm warnings, which will go away with the next released version.

Comment: @jdoe workaround: http://blog.siteos.de/java/javaee/chroniclemap/2016/05/16/How-To-Use-ChronicleMap-With-JavaEE.html Going away from dynamic compilation completely is on the project roadmap, too, which should eliminate such problems completely.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Googled it before, but didn't know if the generated output can be used with no additional precautions.